# Applying commits from one subtree to another in same repo

Tags: git, version-control

I've been using git-p4 to clone parts of a Perforce repo into a git repo.  The tree I've checked out has the following Perforce "branch" structure:

repo/releaseA 
repo/releaseB 
repo/featureA 
repo/featureB

I have a bunch of git commits in my local git repo to the featureA directory; however, I'd like to "rebase" those commits onto the featureB directory instead.  Is there a way to translate a set of patches/commits that were originally applied to one directory onto another instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.  If your commits affect *only* `repo/featureA` this'll be very easy:

```
mkdir patches
git format-patch -o patches master..my_featureA_branch

git am patches/* -p3 --directory=repo/featureB
```

and you're done.

If your commits change files outside repo/featureA you need to strip those out,

```
cat >mystuff.sed <<\EOD
/^(From [0-9a-f]{40}|diff --git )/!{H;$!d}
x
/^From /b
${h;s,.*--,--,;x}
\,^diff[^\n]* [ab]/repo/featureA/,!{$!d;x;b}
${p;x}
EOD
```

and

```
sed -s -i -r -f mystuff.sed patches/*
```

before the `git am`.  Any patches that didn't affect anything at all in `repo/featureA` you'll have to `git am --skip` in that case.

Comment: The first case is exactly what I needed.  However, I had to use "-p2" to get it to work because the "repo" dir in my example is actually the root.

Comment: >5 min edit: I used "-p2" and "--directory=featureB" because the "repo" dir is the repo root.

Answer (score 0):

- if you only want to pick one single commit then use,

  `git cherry-pick <commit-id>`
- if you want to apply a series of commit starting from `C1` to `Cx`, then use [rebase --onto](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html)

  `git rebase --onto featureB C1 Cx`

Comment: The questioner wants to know how to *rebase* commits from one directory to another from within the *same* git repository. So how will your answer help?

Comment: 'I have a bunch of git commits in my local git repo to the featureA directory' means the OP has more than one repos!

Comment: For me it sounds he only has one git repo. I will ask

Comment: @villekulla `rebase` has a specific meaning in git, that isn't what OP's after.

Comment: @jthill I understand. For somewhat he wrote *"rebase"* instead of *rebase*. I just wanted to state that in may opinion the OP only has one git repo, and he just wants to apply a number of commits from on subdirectory to another.

Comment: @villekulla commits are to the entire repo, what do you mean by commits from one subdirectory?

Comment: @ZacWrangler Title of the question reads: *"Applying commits from one subtree to another in same repo"*. He talks about subtrees of the same repository. He is not asking how to do standard cherry-pick or standard rebase.

Comment: @villekulla please show me how you can have two subdirectory in a same repo, while for each directory you have the different commits!

Comment: @ZacWrangler Sorry, it's clear, one commit is always for the whole repository. The OP asks how to apply partial commits of one subdirectory to another. Please look at jthill's answer. I didn't check it, but on first glance it looks ok.