# replay git commits on repo with different root

Tags: git, smartgit

I am one of the current maintainers of the [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) project on sourceforge. This code is stored in an SVN repo, but to stimulate contributions of others, I want to make a git repo available. I already have a git-svn clone of the svn trunk up on github currently at [github](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/) (made through [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/svn-index), which is not really compatible with git-svn actually).

I made this by cloning `https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freeglut/code/trunk/freeglut`. However, I now find that I should have cloned `https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freeglut/code` and have SmartGit's svn bridge figure out the branches and trunk.

I have made this new correct clone locally. Now the problem: I already have a few commits in my local git repo of the old/wrong clone. I would like to transfer these over to my new repo, but as the root directories on disk are not the same, a simple rebase strategy as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404628/how-do-i-join-two-git-repos-without-a-common-root-where-all-modified-files-are) would not work (I think).

I could do it with patches, as `git apply` has the `--directory` argument to prefix the paths in the patch files that would make things work, but then I would have to do it commit by commit. At least, I have not found a way to put multiple commits in a single patch file (without squashing) and replay them all on top of my `HEAD`.

How to I best solve my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying commits from one subtree to another in same repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326233/applying-commits-from-one-subtree-to-another-in-same-repo)

Comment: @jthill, you are right, that does appear to be a duplicate. I didn't consider those search terms...

Comment: Why would it be, it's not about the SAME repo but a different one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that:

1. [`git format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) can generate a file containing a range of commits, such as a whole branch.
2. [`git am`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) with the `--directory` option can replay the commits contained in the patch file one by one ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply)) and commit them for me.

Problem solved!

Comment: nice answer.I didn't think this question this way.

Comment: The secret sauce to `git format-patch` seems to be the `--root` flag ([How to use git format-patch on initial commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197908/4759433)). However, another option is to `git remote add other git@example.com:user/repo.git && git fetch other && git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-ff other/master -m "Merge history from other"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you could do it with patches.

1. Reset last commit by using `git reset --soft 'HEAD^'`. or if you have 3 commits. just do
   `git reset --soft HEAD~3`
2. Do patches.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit?answertab=votes#tab-top) explain it well.

Comment: thanks for the help! However, I don't see why i would want to reset head and then do patches, I have a clean head and only patches to apply.